# Create src/test/resources in Maven Netbeans 8.x with no manual intervention

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

The default war and jar archetypes inside Netbeans don't create a src/test/resources and src/test/java directory.

Is there an easy way of creating src/test/resources inside a Maven project without going to the 'Files' tab or creating the directory manually ?

src/test/java gets created when you create a new unit test.

Most of the Netbeans Maven controls are really intuitive, but manually creating the directory is clumsy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the new file wizard to create a new folder.

1. Right click the parent node of the project and choose "New > Folder..." or choose "File > New File > Other > Folder"
2. Name the folder `src/test/java` with a parent folder left blank.
3. Click finish and the `Test Packages` folder will appear.
4. Repeat for `src/test/resources`
5. It seems [a bug prevents the `Other Test Sources` from being recognised immediately](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=250824), thus you must reload the pom by right clicking the project > Reload POM.

Comment: Thanks. It still seems very clumsy and manual. I was hoping for something profound and easy to explain to junior developers. :)

Comment: On the positive side to junior devs this method teaches them about the magen strucfure, especially if you get them to go to the console to create the directory structure. IMHO i would probably teach them to use the archtype directly from maven at the command line to help them understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

To create new source folder,

1. Right click on maven project --->Click on Build Path ----->Click on New Source Folder
2. New source folder window will open, give the name to your folder example - src/test/source
3. click on Finish